# How solr do ranking of indexed documents

Tags: solr, ranking

I have indexed some documents in solr successfully and now I want to do ranking of these documents. Can anyone guide me how ranking is done in solr with some reference?

Answer (score 0):

Solr is built on top of lucene so it extends the same mechanism of scoring documents. This link should be helpful http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/scoring.html.
You can control ranking of documents while indexing and specifying a boost parameter
See `SolrInputDocument.setDocumentBoost()` and `SolrInputField.setBoost`. The higher the value you specify the higher the document rank will be in the search result.
Additionally you can also specify boost to your query search field.

Comment: I want to change scoring for only few documents so that they should appear on top in search list